# node.js socket.io not working on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

Everything is working running local, but when pushed to Microsoft Azure:

```
http://...... /socket.io/socket.io.js
```

Unable to find this socket.io.js file, a file generated when using socket.io.

What I have tried:
1) I have tried different ports, I have seen some say port 81 for the server to listen on.

2) I am working on a Mac - I can see that you can to do some power shell stuff. 
This totally takes out the simplicity out of Node.js.

3) var port = process.env.port || 1337;

4) looked at: 
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/app-using-socketio/

5) Creating a "Worker Role" on a mac, with Powershell. Not possible?

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

if your on a mac, I would suggest deploying to windows Azure web sites, you get simplicity and scale.

Comment: will socket.io work with Windows Azure Web Sites?  Are they running IIS 8?

Comment: Socket.io will "work" (in that it will fall back to another transport, like long polling), but to my knowledge, socket.io has to be confined to a single server unless you implement a "store" for horizontal scalability. (The only implementation I know of relies on Redis.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer question #5, you can't really create a Windows Azure Cloud Service on a non-Windows OS. All the tools are Windows-only. (The package you need to create is, in fact, a zip file, but it's such a weird zip file that I haven't seen a solution yet for creating it without the tools in the Windows Azure SDK.)